# Chartjs zoom plugin timeout

Tags: angular, chart.js

I need to set a timeout on the zoom plugin of chartjs [link](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/).

The problem is I tried to set a variable on the 'enabled' field like this but it didn't work.

```
zoom: {
    zoom: {
         wheel: {
             enabled: this.allowZoom,
         },
         pinch: {
             enabled: true
         },
         mode: 'x',
     }
}
```

I can't use a `onWheel: () => {}` that would solve this problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution, need to use the variable that contains your Chart.
First set your wheel to enabled 'false'.

```
@ViewChild('chart') canvas: ElementRef;
const ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement;
this.chart = new Chart(ctx,{
...
zoom: {
    zoom: {
         wheel: {
             enabled: false,
         },
         pinch: {
             enabled: true
         },
         mode: 'x',
     }
   }
})
```

Then create a mouseenter and mouseleave on your canvas div.

```
<div (mouseenter)="mouseEnter()" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave()">
  <canvas #chart></canvas>
</div>
```

To finish use two timeout, one so the user won't be able to scroll into the canvas before 1s, and another one so the user can out and in with 1s delay and still be able to scroll.

```
zoomEnterTimeout: any
zoomLeaveTimeout: any

mouseEnter() {
    clearTimeout(this.zoomLeaveTimeout)
    this.zoomEnterTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.infrastructureChart.options.plugins.zoom.zoom.wheel.enabled = true
        this.infrastructureChart.update()
    }, 1000)
}

mouseLeave() {
    clearTimeout(this.zoomEnterTimeout)
    this.zoomLeaveTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.infrastructureChart.options.plugins.zoom.zoom.wheel.enabled = false
        this.infrastructureChart.update()
    }, 1000)
}
```